# Apply style to <span> contents only if they are not descendants of <pre>

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'd like to apply a given style (red colored in the minimal example below) to `<span>` contents only if they are **not** descendants of `<pre>`.

Here is a minimal HTML code:

```html
<pre>
  <span>
    Inside pre.
  </span>
</pre>

<span>
  Outside pre.
</span>
```

I manage to do the exact contrary with the following CSS code:

```css
pre span {
  color: red;
}
```

which apply the style to `<span>` contents only if they **are** descendants of `<pre>`. I tried many combinations, such as the following one:

```css
:not(pre) span {
  color: red;
}
```

but with no success (the previous one applies the style to all spans, regardless they are or not descendants of `<pre>`.

How could I achieve the expected result?

Comment: Won't `:not(pre) > span` be enough?

Comment: `:not(pre) span` won't work because it's targeting all spans that are descendants of all elements *and not `pre`*." So even though a `span` may be excluded as a descendant of `pre`, it's included because it's a descendant of elements higher up. The child combinator (`>`) solves this problem, because it targets only `span` elements that are children of `pre`.

Comment: Take a look at Josep's answer in the duplicate. In 2012 when the answer was written, it didn't work, but in 2023 it does.

Comment: @Alohci Indeed, that does the trick. Would you like to add a reply with the code specifically answering my question? If not, I'll add a comment with this code.

Answer (score 1):

```css
:not(pre) > span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <span>
    Inside pre.
  </span>
</pre>

<span>
  Outside pre.
</span>
```

Comment: The question says "not descendants of `<pre>`". A child (`>`) is only one type of descendant. Your solution wouldn't work if the `span` was another type of descendant. (Although perhaps this is the solution the OP was looking for.)

Comment: Indeed, the `span` is not necessarily a direct descendant of the `pre`.